# Share Android Studio project between different Windows & Mac machines

Tags: windows, macos, android-studio

I have an Android Studio project built under Windows, now when I copy all folder to Mac and try to open it in Mac version of Android Studio it prompts for lots of error, most them pointing to a path on Windows machine.
How can I modify project so all paths be relative and not machine (or absolute path) dependent?

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't have to modify anything because the shareable files shouldn't have absolute paths in them at all. Share only the source files and build script files (**build.gradle** and **settings.gradle** and the Gradle wrapper files). Don't share project files (**.iml** files or the **.idea** folder). Don't share the **local.properties** file, which is local to an individual machine.

Comment: is it possible for a team to have mac and windows machine for a same android project and can they work simultaneously?