# error: resource array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs

Tags: android, xml, fonts, font-family

I'm getting following error in my fonts xml.

**anton.xml**

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="Anton"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

At this line it says cannot resolve symbol:

```
error: resource array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
```

Before it worked, but i copied my project from my macbook to a windows pc and for some reason i get this error now.

I tried removing the font and even tried another one but still getting the same error.

Comment: A clean and build should work fine.

Comment: @ReazMurshed tried but doesn't work still says Android resource linking failed

Comment: I see. Have to tried `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` as well? Please let me know.

Comment: @ReazMurshed also tried that, really weird because on my macbook i'm not getting this error.

Comment: It looks weird to me too. I would try gradle clean as well. I am not sure what else might be the reason.

Comment: @ReazMurshed what i did though was removing .DS_STORE files that were showing up in my apps folder, because i thought i wouldn't need them that im now working on a windows pc and not macbook.

Comment: @ReazMurshed could that be the reason?

Comment: No. I do not think so. Usually cleaning files and removing the `.idea/` folders do not have any effect. You might consider removing the `./idea` folders too if there are any.

Comment: I would like to suggest keeping the files which are necessary only. And then sync with gradle. This will download the other files which are necessary. See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51052946/3145960).

Comment: @ReazMurshed Removing the ./idea folder resolved the error. Thanks!

Comment: Great to know that. I am putting it as an answer hoping that might help some other developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, cleaning and rebuilding the project works just fine when you are moving your Android project from the mac to windows. You might have to do a `File > Invalidate Cache/Restart` as well. If that is still showing the error, you might also want to do a gradle clean. Actually, the files you should really care about are the following.

```
app/
    src/
    build.gradle
build.gradle 
settings.gradle
```

Hence you can remove all other files except these. In this case, deleting the `./idea` folders did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into the same issue. In my case, I didn't move my project. What I found out was that an error had occurred during font declaration.

- The following was missing: `@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs`
- The solution was to define it in the `res/values/font_certs.xml` file.
- So, it would be best if you ended up with the above file looking as follows;

  ```
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
         <array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
             <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev</item>
            <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod</item>
         </array>
         <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev">
             <item>
                 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
             </item>
         </string-array>
         <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod">
             <item>
                 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
             </item>
         </string-array>
     </resources>`
  ```
- I hope this helps either when invalidating caches, rebuilding project and cleaning project solutions fail or when you find `@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs` missing or not declared.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change pespective from android to project;
2. Delete path `./idea` and `./gradle`
3. Click on Invalidate and Restart

Finish, go be happy!