# Android View in Project tab of Android Studio keeps loading forever

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, kotlin

Today I got my new Macbook and installed Android Studio. When I tried to open my Kotlin project, everything works perfectly but the Android project view is loading forever.

[image]

I created a new sample project and it loads correctly. I also have this project on a Win laptop and it loads fine too.

Does anyone have an idea why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have just copied and pasted the project from your windows machine, you should expect some undefined behavior like this. Because there are some files included into the project specifically for windows OS. You should use git instead of copy pasting things. Or if you rather not at this point,
[How to transfer an Android Studio Project from Windows to Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052904/how-to-transfer-an-android-studio-project-from-windows-to-mac-os-x/51053037) Here is the files you need to delete to make things working on your mac.

Comment: Yes, of course I use Git to manage my project.

Answer (score 1):

Please delete

.idea
.gradle

files from project and then open project again.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** I just uninstall the 4.1.3 version and use the beta version 4.2 rc1 and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I accidently created an infinite view loop in my xml design and every time i try to render it, I ended up with no view loading and memory errors. So i had a file name item_patient.xml for use with recycler view and inside the file was another recycler view and inside the code for that recycler view i mentioned item_patient.xml as its list item for rendering.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_value_array"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_patient" // THIS LINE HERE
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_8sdp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_date"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

so it tried to render a view containing itself infinitely which ended up not rendering and memoy errors and stuff. All i had to do was remove

```
tools:listitem="@layout/item_patient" // THIS LINE HERE
```

and since it did not have to render it. i was able to create a view inside itself in a nested recycler view. and got the error removed as well.

p.s. @mehmoodnisar125's answer of deleting .idea and .gradle helped clear up the memory for me to find out the error.